# Popup window width resizing when not needed

Tags: css

So I have this thing popup-window on my homepage that I fill with some content. The problem I'm having with it is that it's resizeing way to early.

I don't want the popup to resize before getting to big for the window to handle.
How am I going to solve this? Been at it for some time, can't figure it out.

You can try it out in the jsiffle url, resize the width of the preview window and you'll see it shrinks before it's even needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/82gvnamL/

CSS:

```
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    z-index: 2;
}
#popup #loading {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: url('../img/ajax-loading.gif') no-repeat;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#popup #container {
    max-width: 95%;
    max-height: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #111;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#popup #content {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 16px;
}

#popup #close {
    width: 20px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: right;
    background: #222;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: -7px;

    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 12px;

    cursor: pointer;
}
#popup #close:before {
    content: 'X';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="close"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Very long string in here that should not get cut off until window width is too small. If you understand what I'm saying.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fix width of popup container. http://jsfiddle.net/82gvnamL/1/

Comment: What do you mean? #popup is the background that "fades" the homepage when the popupwindow is active. I need the window to be dynamic but still adjust itself to the content. EDIT: I can't have a fixed width on it since it should "shrink" to it's content.

Comment: Fix width of container it will not adjust see demo i mentaioned

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. The container should have an dynamic width so it can contain any content. It should only shrink if it exceeds the browser window width. Yours never resizes at all, meaning it wont adjust it self to the content within.

Comment: What you want it should not resize on window resize?

Comment: I don't want it to resize unless the containers width is greather than the browser window. The width of #container should be the width of the content inside it. Like in my example, it resizes even though it has a lot of space on the left & right it could use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the container's width like so"

`#popup #container {
max-width: 255px;
width: 75%;
}`

So on larger screens it will be a fixed width of 255px and on smaller screens it will shrink to 75% width.